# RxJava. Change chain in compose

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, flatmap

I have the code:

```
 return channelRepository.getRssFeedContent(channel.getSourceLink())
                .toObservable()
                .map(this::parseItem)
                .flatMapIterable(xmlItemRawObjects -> xmlItemRawObjects)
                .compose(/* question  */)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler());
```

Using xmlItemRawObjects I need to make a query to the database, check if the record exists. If no record exists, return the same xmlItemRawObjects from compose() to continue working with it.
If the record exists in the database, then make sure that compose() skips the element for the stream.

I tried to create a function:

```
        .compose(new ObservableTransformer<XmlItemRawObject, XmlItemRawObject>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<XmlItemRawObject> apply(Observable<XmlItemRawObject> upstream) {
               Boolean isExists = false;
               Observable<Item> test = Observable.create(emitter -> {
                   upstream
                           .flatMap(xmlItemRawObject -> channelRepository.getItemByUniqueId(xmlItemRawObject.getGuid())
                           .subscribe(item -> isExists = true));
               });
            }
        })
```

but it works just fine. Thank you for your advice.

P.S. No examples from compose() at all.

I've tried to solve the problem through flatmap:

```
        .flatMap(new Function<XmlItemRawObject, ObservableSource<XmlItemRawObject>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<XmlItemRawObject> apply(XmlItemRawObject xmlItemRawObject) throws Exception {
                                       Observable<XmlItemRawObject> test = Observable.create(emitter -> {
                    channelRepository.getItemByUniqueId(xmlItemRawObject.getGuid())
                            .subscribe(
                                    item -> {
                                        emitter.onComplete();
                                    }, throwable -> {}, () -> Observable.just(xmlItemRawObject));
                });
                return test.defaultIfEmpty(xmlItemRawObject);
            }})
```

Can't check an empty "subquery" result, make an if-else construct to pass on the xmlItemRawObject along the chain

Comment: Why are you even using `compose`? Compose is there to transform the entire sequence above it to something else, such as apply common schedulers or logging. Also the code you provided doesn't even compile as it is missing a return statement and `isExist` can't be modified from the inner lambda.

Comment: That's right, it's not compiling because I can't find a solution.
I tried to solve the problem through flatmap (changed the message above).